# Stretch the corners of a plane to stretch a contained quadrilateral into a rectangle? (Image given)

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-manipulation

I need to figure out where to stretch the vertices of the plane so the quadrilateral (in blue) fills the space previously filled by the undistorted plane. I have the coordinates of the vertices of the quadrilateral, but it changes every frame. I need the algorithm to work in real time. It should be something like how the corner pin effect works in Photoshop. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Before and after]